# Foursquare Map doesn't render in OnsenUI tags

Tags: javascript, html, foursquare, onsen-ui

I currently writing an application which need to show map from foursquare. I tested in simple html and it's work well. But It turn out white blank page when I tried to embed in OnsenUI tags. The Code as follows.

**Javascript**

```
ons.ready(function() {


      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(data) {


    var lat = data['coords']['latitude'];
    var lng = data['coords']['longitude'];

    /* Create map. */


    L.mapbox.accessToken = 'sometokenhere';

    var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'myname.myid').setView([lat, lng], 15);

    //map.attributionControl.addAttribution('<a href="https://foursquare.com/">Places data from Foursquare</a>');


    // Create a Foursquare developer account: https://developer.foursquare.com/
    // NOTE: CHANGE THESE VALUES TO YOUR OWN:
    // Otherwise they can be cycled or deactivated with zero notice.
    var CLIENT_ID = 'something';
    var CLIENT_SECRET = 'somewhere';

     // https://developer.foursquare.com/start/search
    var API_ENDPOINT = 'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search' +
      '?client_id=CLIENT_ID' +
      '&client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET' +
      '&v=20130815' +
      '&ll='+lat+','+lng+
      '&query=food' +
      '&callback=?';

    // Keep our place markers organized in a nice group.
    var foursquarePlaces = L.layerGroup().addTo(map);

    $.getJSON(API_ENDPOINT
      .replace('CLIENT_ID', CLIENT_ID)
      .replace('CLIENT_SECRET', CLIENT_SECRET)
      .replace('LATLON', map.getCenter().lat +
          ',' + map.getCenter().lng), function(result, status) {

      if (status !== 'success') return alert('Request to Foursquare failed');

      // Transform each venue result into a marker on the map.
      for (var i = 0; i < result.response.venues.length; i++) {
        var venue = result.response.venues[i];
        var latlng = L.latLng(venue.location.lat, venue.location.lng);
        var marker = L.marker(latlng, {
            icon: L.mapbox.marker.icon({
              'marker-color': '#BE9A6B',
              'marker-symbol': 'cafe',
              'marker-size': 'large'
            })
          })
        .bindPopup('<strong><a href="https://foursquare.com/v/' + venue.id + '">' +
          venue.name + '</a></strong>')
          .addTo(foursquarePlaces);

      }

    });
  });

    });
```

**markup**

```
<div id="map"></div>
```

That code is work well but

```
  <script type="text/ons-template" id="detail.html">
  <ons-navigator title="Navigator" var="myNavigator">
    <ons-page>

      <div id="map"></div>
    </ons-page>

  </script>
```

this code isn't work. Could you show me a way to solve it. Thank you

Comment: The way you use OnsenUI tag is for the AngularJS template. If this is what you want, you will need to create an AngularJS directive and point to that template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used within Angular Controller and mutate on $scope variable. but If I used other controller, I have to copy all the stuffs too. The clear and concise ways of solving is wrote as Service and inject on controller. but my solution is just hardcoding in controller.

```
module.controller('RandomController',function($scope,$data){


    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(data) {

      var lat = data['coords']['latitude'];
      var lng = data['coords']['longitude'];


      L.mapbox.accessToken = 'Something';

      var map = L.mapbox.map('map','youraccount'); 

      map.setView([lat, lng], 13);


      var CLIENT_ID = 'your_client_id';
      var CLIENT_SECRET = 'your_client_secret';


      var API_ENDPOINT = 'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search' +
        '?client_id=' + CLIENT_ID+
        '&client_secret='+CLIENT_SECRET +
        '&v=20130815' +
        '&ll='+lat+','+lng+
        '&query=food' +
        '&callback';   


      var foursquarePlaces = L.layerGroup().addTo(map);

      $.getJSON(API_ENDPOINT
        .replace('CLIENT_ID', CLIENT_ID)
        .replace('CLIENT_SECRET', CLIENT_SECRET)
        .replace('LATLON', map.getCenter().lat +',' + map.getCenter().lng), function(result, status) {

          if (status !== 'success') return alert('Request to Foursquare failed');

          // Transform each venue result into a marker on the map.

             var venues = result.response.venues;

             var shuffled_venues = shuffle(venues);

             $scope.$apply(function(){
              $scope.products = shuffled_venues;
            });

          for (var i = 0; i < result.response.venues.length; i++) {
            var venue = result.response.venues[i];
            var latlng = L.latLng(venue.location.lat, venue.location.lng);
            var marker = L.marker(latlng, {
                icon: L.mapbox.marker.icon({
                  'marker-color': '#BE9A6B',
                  'marker-symbol': 'cafe',
                  'marker-size': 'large'
                })
              })
          .addTo(foursquarePlaces);

          }

       });
    },function(error){
      console.log(error.message);

    },{
        enableHighAccuracy: true
        ,timeout : 5000
    });

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Onsen UI tag need a small amount of time to be interpreted and converted to the html tag. So I think the script tried to embed map in the html, however Onsen UI tag have not been converted yet. 
How about try to use $timeout() to wait for converting Onsen UI tag? And what error message you received?